# Magento 2 : Display Customer Attribute in Grid

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have a Customer Attribute with Image Type.

Its working Good all in all areas. I would like to display that attribute in Customer Listing same as Product Image.

How to do this? Any ideas will be appreciated.

**Update**

```
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $setup->startSetup();

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $setup->startSetup();
    $attributesInfo = [
        'photo_id' => [
            'label' => 'Photo ID',
            'type' => 'text',
            'input' => 'select',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1000,
        ]
    ];
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }
    $magentoUsernameAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'photo_id');
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->addData(
        [
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'],
        ]
    );
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->save();
```

Comment: could you update your question with your setup/InstallData.php file code.

Comment: Make sure your attribute is in default attribute set of customer entity, and assigned it to a group (see table eav_attribute_group). And you need to add you attribute in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`.

Comment: And your install data should also have: 'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,

Comment: I noticed that if user_defined = true than the attribute might not be in the attribute set.

Comment: Can you update your whole code to your question?

Answer (score 6):

1.You need to add 'is_used_in_grid' => true, in your InstallData.php for attribute options.

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup; 

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactor
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;    

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }    

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
         /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'photo_id', [
            'photo_id' => [
            'label' => 'Photo ID',
            'type' => 'text',
            'input' => 'select',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        ]
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'photo_id')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

2.Create file **customer_listing.xml** in app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <column name="photo_id" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PhotoId">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Photo Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

3.Create file **PhotoId.php** inVendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;


class PhotoId extends Column
{
    protected $customerFactory;

    private $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {   
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($item["entity_id"]);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = '<img src='.$this->_urlBuilder->getBaseUrl(['_type' => UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]).'customer'.$customer->getData('photo_id').'/>';

            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```